# Kotlin: @Ignore'd properties persisted by Sugar ORM

Tags: android, kotlin, sugarorm

In my Android app, I'm using Kotlin in conjunction with SugarORM and I have encountered an issue trying to prevent some properties from being persisted. Ironically, the `@com.orm.dsl.Ignore` annotation seems to be ignored when used in Kotlin classes.

As an example,

1) let's declare two seemingly identical models:

```
// JavaUser.java
public class JavaUser extends SugarRecord {
    public String login = "login";
    @Ignore public String password = "password";
}

// KotlinUser.kt
class KotlinUser : SugarRecord() {
    var login: String = "login"
    @Ignore var password: String = "password"
}
```

2) persist their instances

```
JavaUser().save()
KotlinUser().save()
```

3) and take a look at what's actually being persisted:

```
sqlite> select * from java_user;
ID|LOGIN
1|login

sqlite> select * from kotlin_user;
ID|LOGIN|PASSWORD
1|login|password
```

I realize that it may have something to do with Kotlin annotation processing but I'm just not sure how I can go about it. Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: I tried to dig into the Sugar ORM sources (here's [the most relevant part](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/blob/ca5dd14df77d4a78047197f223eaf1b0f6c50c16/library/src/main/java/com/orm/util/ReflectionUtil.java)) and to reproduce your problem to see what happens inside Sugar ORM. But, surprisingly, `getTableFields` returns only the `login` field when called on your `KotlinUser` class. Could you please re-check if the problem is actually in Sugar ORM persisting `KotlinUser::password`? Maybe the entry comes from some of the previous runs...

Comment: Well, I actually created a new project from scratch to reproduce this behavior. For what it's worth, here's the [source](https://github.com/squeezymo/SugarORMTest); I also applied two solutions from @voddan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core difference between your Java and Kotlin code is that in Java you use fields, but in Kotlin you use properties. See the [Properties and Fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#properties-and-fields) section in documentation.

You may try the following solutions and see what works best with SugarORM:

#### 1. Make Kotlin expose fields:

```
@Ignore @JvmField var password: String = "password"
```

#### 2. Apply your annotation to the private backing field:

```
@field:Ignore var password: String = "password"
```

Comment: As far as I see, [`@Ignore`](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/blob/ca5dd14df77d4a78047197f223eaf1b0f6c50c16/library/src/main/java/com/orm/annotation/Ignore.java) has target `FIELD`, so it should be applied to the field implicitly, without specifying `@field:`.

Comment: Yes, check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/h0tk3y/cb178ea938bdcfc78bc772755c49c0d8).

Comment: At this point, it seems to me like the problem is not in `@Ignore` (please see my comment to the question for details).

Comment: I tried the first approach and it didn't help. But targeting did the trick.